# Is "Bad Line Breaking" obsolete with "use strict"?

Tags: javascript, jslint, use-strict

Please assume  'use strict';  and also assume that, JSLint is on and errors cannot be ignored.

I find operators and ',' initiated lists so much more readable,

e.g.:

```
var i = 0
    , j = 1
    , someLongVariablename1
    , someLongVariablename2
    , someLongVariablename3
    , someLongVariablename4;

 if( (
     'dcr' === cmd
      && (action)
      && ('get' === actionHttp || 'post' === actionHttp )
      && whatever
   ) { ... }
```

Hence my question:
Is "Bad Line Breaking" obsolete with "use strict"?

EDITED:  'use strict';  will not prevent the execution of bad line breaking the code. It can prevent the execution of some kinds of errors.

I see that JSLint and JSHint treat bad line breaking differently.  JSHint is much friendlier towards the syntax I prefer.

So that, may be a solution for others who are working on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, [strict mode](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-C) doesn't disable the horror that is [automatic semicolon insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9), and so "bad" line breaks remain an issue. For example:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  console.log(foo());

  function foo() {
    var a = 1, b = 2;

    return
    a + b;
  }
})();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/erukab/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/erukab/1/edit) (you need to open the console and look at it)

That still logs `undefined` rather than `3`, because ASI kicks in and adds a semicolon after the `return` in `foo`.

Comment: We are using very strict settings in JSLint.  The code you wrote is a complete JSLint anti-pattern, as JSLint gives three errors:

* expected ; error
* unreachable code error

Comment: I edited the question:  I am assuming rigorous use of JSLint, so that execution will NOT proceed if JSLint errors are in place. However, that really complicates the question... originally a simple question and your answer is a simply right.

Am marking your answer right.